# MongoDB -- Failed global initialization: Failed to open "var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"

Tags: mongodb-3.0

I am getting errors starting Mongod v3.0.15 in Debian linux.  I had changed the `/etc/mongod.conf` file to use smallFiles by adding `mmapv1: smallFiles: true` to the storage options.

I now get the following error when I execute `$mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`:

> ib1:/ 514 $ mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
>
> 2017-10-03T12:14:21.183-0500 F CONTROL  Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"

The `mongod.log` file exists, and it is also defined in the `mongod.conf` file as in that directory.

I am able to open the /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log file myself in the shell.  It hasn't been written to in a long time (months) curiously.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much,
Karen

Comment: Is mongo already/still running (is the file locked by something)?

Comment: No, it's not already running.  I'm the only one using it.  I have also tried restarting the server with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: What is the permission for mongod.log ?

Comment: ib1:~ 504 $ ls -l /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 39858 Oct  3 13:34 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Answer (score 3):

You may need to change the permissions for the parents directory /var/log/ as the user running the mongod instance might not have access to it. The below code should do it

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/log
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `cd /var/log`
2. `sudo mkdir -m 777 mongodb`
3. `sudo service mongod start`
4. `sudo service mongod status`

Hopefully that will do!