# MongoDB --- Failed global initialization: Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongod-config.log"

Tags: mongodb, configuration, sharding

I'm trying to setup the config servers for mongodb sharding. I created a specific config file that is set to log to `/var/log/mongodb/mongod-config.log`.

When I run `mongod --config <path-to-config-file>`, I get this error:

```
`F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open 
"/var/log/mongodb/mongod-config.log"`
```

When I run the same command but with `sudo`, it runs but there's no output.

But then when I try starting the mongo shell at the port (27019) specified by my config file, I get this:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27019/test
2018-05-01T03:13:13.399+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 
127.0.0.1:27019, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection 
refused
2018-05-01T03:13:13.400+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to 
server 127.0.0.1:27019, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I'm just following the [MongoDB sharding documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)

I've seen some of the previous posts on here and one was the [same problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187549/mongodb-failed-global-initialization-failed-to-open-var-log-mongodb-mongod). No solution there, but I want to try again and see if anybody has a solution to this.

Not sure if I missed something or what the issue is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I have figured out my own question.

Firstly, the issue was that since I was using a different port 27019 for the config servers, I needed to open that port from the firewall.

Second, **I changed the dbPath** in my config file from `/var/lib/mongodb` to `/data/db` since that is the default path for mongodb to store data.

Make sure to run `sudo service mongod restart` after.

With that done, I was able to start mongod with my specific config file:

```
sudo mongod --config <path-to-config-file>
```

The key is to include `sudo` for me. That solved the issue of:

```
F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open 
"/var/log/mongodb/mongod-config.log"
```

After running the command, I see that mongod has started on my virtual machine (vm) and now I am able to connect to the mongo shell of said vm from another machine with:

```
mongo <ip_address_of_said_vm>:27019
```

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem while trying to start mongodb service in my Debian9 64bit server.  I could see the below information while checking status.

```
:~# systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-02-22 14:52:17 CET; 11s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 20914 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20914 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 22 14:52:17 server-test systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Feb 22 14:52:17 server-test mongod[20914]: 2019-02-22T14:52:17.650+0100
F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
Feb 22 14:52:17 server-test systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 22 14:52:17 server-test systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 22 14:52:17 server-test systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have also got detailed information of each start command result in `"/var/log/daemon.log"`.  I could see the information `"Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"` which was one of the clue for the issue.  While checking i could see mongod.log file was under root ownership and service was starting under the user "mongodb".  So applied the below fix.

```
fix1: -  chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

While trying to start again, i could see service showing new error this time in "daemon.log"

```
mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
```

This error caused as mongodb file storage location has issues and unable to access its files.

```
fix2.  chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/*
```

See the screen shot attached.  Now I am able to start the service.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Default, MongoDB creates the log file at this path `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`, if the log file is not found, please check with the MongoDB config file.

**logpath**

Check the MongoDB config file at `/etc/mongod.conf` or `/yourMongoDBpath/mongod.conf`, the logpath defined where to log.

```
/etc/mongod.conf
```

> $ cat /etc/mongod.conf
>       # mongod.conf
>
> Where to store the data.
>
> Note: if you run mongodb as a non-root user (recommended) you may
>   need to create and set permissions for this directory manually,
>   e.g., if the parent directory isn't mutable by the mongodb user.
>
> ```
> dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
> ```
>
> where to log
>
> ```
> logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
> ```
>
> ## ...

**For Example**

Here i am mentioning one `mongod.conf` file with `dbpath` and `logpath`. And i shall show here how to start the `mongod` server as well as `mongo` shell.

```
sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr
replication:
  replSetName: repltest
security:
  keyFile: /var/mongodb/pki/replkeyfile
net:
  bindIp: localhost,192.168.103.100
  port: 26001
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/mongodb/db/csrs1/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
storage:
  dbPath: /var/mongodb/db/csrs1
~
```

Then to start mongod with --fork , used the command such as

```
/var/mongodb/db/csrs1$ mongod -f csrs1.conf
```

> about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for
>   connections. forked process: 2101 child process started successfully,
>   parent exiting

And to start the mongo shell

```
mongo --port 26001
```

Some of the MongoDB jira blog related to error [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-3425) and [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13515).

For further your ref [here](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-where-is-the-log-file/)  and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-suse/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own logFile in your own directory.  You can't use the existing `mongod.log`.  If you try to write to the `mongod.log` file that came with the MongoDB installation, you'll get *Failed to Open* and *Access is Denied*.

If you are running Mongo on a Windows laptop, you should start it with a command similar to this:

```sh
mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2" --logpath "C:\MongoData\data.log"
```

where `C:\MongoData\data.log` is an empty file I created in a new directory.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows OS, I had that same problem.
The problem was permission of the file.
Then, in file "mongod.log" in "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\log" didn't have permission to write. Then, in "properties" of the file, aba "Security" in I put permission to "write".